# Limitations of electromagnetic emanations techniques (such as TEMPEST)

Tags: wireless

### Target isolation

Attacks like TEMPEST seems to work well but what happen if you are one meter away with two or more computers on, let's say the same table ?

I suppose that the recording device will capture all the electronic emanation from all the device where the target is, so if two other running laptop are on the same table as the target who can you interpret the data properly.

### Range

Also at what distance can operate TEMPEST ? [Here](http://www.tau.ac.il/~tromer/radioexp/) you can read:

> With this enhanced setup, the attack can be mounted from 50 cm away. Using better antennas, amplifiers and digitizers, the range can be extended even further.

Even further ? Across the street for example ? What happen if there's walls in between ?

Answer (score 1):

The original BBC program, where a Van Eck device was used to screendump CRT screens (high current, high voltage devices) was from at least a hundred meters, with a directional antenna. Yagi I believe. LCD/etc screens are similarly vulnerable, as are keyboards (10-15KHz within 10-15 metres).

There are two things worth noting. Normal cops won't know how to operate this equipment. @Schroeder can perhaps elaborate, I know he is an IT spook. Second, the tempest shielding can be done by anyone. And you can use a spark gap generator to completely f?ck the radio spectrum; everything gets disrupted. But do you really want to do that?

Without having a modern Van Eck device, I will guesstimate that they probably still have a range of ~100-150 metres with a good antenna, and skilled operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 100 meters without walls right ? What happens when you add a wall between the operator and its target ?

Comment: Walls with metal in them, and such? Radiowaves bounce around, and are reflected by metal. What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps I can give a better answer.

Comment: I just try to understand how this attack may work in real life. But 100 meters seems excessive ! Where does this number comes from ? How is it possible to isolate a signal at such distance. If I live in a tower with a lot of laptops around me how can you target one ?

Comment: @Deewy That's a good question - IIRC the operator in the original program (perhaps https://youtu.be/mcV6izFG3vQ ) simply walked the spectrum. No two laptops (unless identical) would leak on the same frequencies.

Comment: Additionally, look at the antitempest font stuff here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/emsec/softtempest-faq.html

Comment: I guesstimate that e.g. a raspberry pi or beaglebone with a not-backlit LCD wouldn't emit anything above the noise floor. I guess that's all you could do to keep your comms away from a well funded attacker.